# TextBox shows numbers instead of words from CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkedlistbox

Beforehand, sorry if this post looks confusing because I'm terrible at English.

How do I make the randomly selected items on `CheckedListBox` to be displayed on `TextBox`? This is my code:

```
private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Clear();
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomtrait = random.Next(1, checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count);
    checkedListBox1.SelectedItem = checkedListBox1.Items[randomtrait];
    string data = randomtrait.ToString();
    textBox1.Text = data;  //but it shows a number rather than text
}
```

I'm still a beginner and self-taught programmer. Thanks.

Comment: data is `randomtrait` which is `int`

Comment: You can fix it by using `string data = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`.

Comment: What would you expect your code to display?

Comment: If I understand what you want then try to replace `textBox1.Text = data`  with `textBox1.Text=checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted my the current comments, since you are displaying the randomtrait, it is an integer and thus you get a number.

I am assuming what you intended to do are as follow. You had checkedListBox that contains multiple items. Since they are able to check multiple items, at the click of this generateButton, you would like to show one of the checked items. If that was your intention, there may be some flaw of logic:

```
private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Clear();
    Random random = new Random();

    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx
    // random.Next is inclusive of lower bound and exclusive on upper bound
    // the way you are accessing array, it is 0 based - thus you may not be able to picked up your first checked item
    int randomtrait = random.Next(1, checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count);

    // this set the 'selectedItem' to be something else from the whole list (rather than the checked items only).
    // checkedListBox1.SelectedItem = checkedListBox1.Items[randomtrait]; 

    // randomtrait is an integer, so data here would be numbers. This explains why next line displaying a number rather than text 
    //string data = randomtrait.ToString();

    textBox1.Text = data; 
}
```

May be what you intended is something like:

```
private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Clear();
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomtrait = random.Next(0, checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count);
    textBox1.Text = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[randomtrait].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You have solved multiple problems I have faced before I created new thread.

Comment: No worries...  =) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I see, your code assigned the randomtrait to your `data` which is your random number:

```
string data = randomtrait.ToString();
```

in order to assign the value of checkedListBox1 your code must be like this:

```
string data = checkedListBox1.SelectedItems[randomtrait].ToString();
```

Comment: Much appreciated. By the way, it gives me an error that `int randomtrait cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type of 'object'`

Comment: Add s in item, instead of `checkedListBox1.SelectedItem[randomtrait].toString();` to 'checkedListBox1.SelectedItems[randomtrait].toString();'